# ffmpeg c# asp.net video conversion error

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, ffmpeg

The following code shows error as "StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet." What is the problem in this code? It requires any changes? It always clear the process by catch exception.

```
static void ExecuteAsync()
            {
                if (File.Exists("Videos/output.flv"))
                try
                {
                    File.Delete("Videos/output.flv");
                }
                catch
                {
                    return;
                }

            try
            {
                process = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"e:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe", "-i cars1.flv -same_quant intermediate1.mpg");
                info.CreateNoWindow = false;
                info.UseShellExecute = false;
                info.RedirectStandardError = true;
                info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo = info;
                process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_ErrorDataReceived);
                process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
                process.Exited += new EventHandler(process_Exited);
                process.Start();
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (process != null) process.Dispose();
            }
        }
        static int lineCount = 0;
        static void process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input line: {0} ({1:m:s:fff})", lineCount++, DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        static void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Output Data Received.");
        }

        static void process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            process.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("Bye bye!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set this to false:

```
info.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
```

Documentation says :

> To use StandardOutput, you must set
>   ProcessStartInfo..::.UseShellExecute to false, and you must set
>   ProcessStartInfo..::.RedirectStandardOutput to true. Otherwise,
>   reading from the StandardOutput stream throws an exception

Comment: i set like u told. and  i removed un defined functions process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine(); now it wont shows any error. But i cant found any converted file as output :(

Comment: if it is large file will take sometime..run task manager and see if ffmpeg is running.

Comment: No dude. It wont show any process as ffmpeg in task manager while executing.

Comment: ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"e:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe", "-i cars1.flv -same_quant intermediate1.mpg"); is this format is right?

Comment: I would suggest to change this to ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"e:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe", "-i "\""C:\cars1.flv"\"" -same_quant "\""C:\intermediate1.mpg"\"""); also add process..WaitForExit(); after process.Start();

Comment: @ Symbol is essential before files or not? because it shows error now as unrecognized escape sequence.

Comment: hey dude... it works :) :) :) :) i place @ symbol infront of "-i and then it works well. Thank you for your kind help dude :) :) :)

Comment: Dude how can we do the same thing when the file is with in the project and how we include ffmpeg in to our project?

Comment: ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"e:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe", "-i ../Videos/cars1.flv -same_quant ../Videos/intermediate1.mpg"); is this right format for that?

Comment: glad it worked..yes this should work or you can use ~/Videos/cars1.flv

Comment: ProcessStartInfo info1 = new ProcessStartInfo(@"e:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe", "-i ~/Videos/cars1.flv -same_quant ~/Videos/intermediate1.mpg"); it wont works dude

Comment: ProcessStartInfo info1 = new ProcessStartInfo(@"e:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe", "-i ~/Videos/cars1.flv -same_quant ~/Videos/intermediate1.mpg"); it wont works dude

Comment: I think you need the full path. You can build your path by getting the location of your app/website by code